# How can I separate double from String

Tags: java, string, sorting, bufferedreader

here is my code. My text is like that

deneme yası yası 89,96,78,89

denkj sdsd sdsdf frfg 98,56,78,54

ddeff fedflşöeşfef 78,85,95,85

I want separated double and string and taking first number like that

output have to be like that

89,96,78,89

98,56,78,54

78,85,95,85

and then I will sort them how can I do that

```
public class PointStatue  {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        ArrayList<String> puan;

        puan = okuDiziyeKoy("C:\\deneme\\posdeneme.txt");
        System.out.format("%d kayıt okundu.%n", puan.size());



        for (int j = 0; j < puan.size(); j++) {

            String item1 = puan.get(j);
            String aa = item1.replaceAll("[\\{\\-\\*\\[\\]\\:\\>]+", "");
            String bb =aa.replaceAll("[\\}]", ",");


            System.out.println(bb);



        }//for end


    }//main end 




    private static ArrayList<String> okuDiziyeKoy(String dosyaAdı) {

        ArrayList<String> dizi = new ArrayList<String>();
        try {
            FileInputStream fIS;
            fIS = new FileInputStream(dosyaAdı);
            Reader r = new InputStreamReader(fIS, "ISO-8859-9");
            BufferedReader bR = new BufferedReader(r);
            String satır;
            while ((satır = bR.readLine()) != null) {
                //Double d = Double.parseDouble(satır);
                dizi.add(satır);
                // System.out.println(satır);
            }
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return dizi;
    }// okuDiziyeKoyEnd


}//class end
```

Comment: Duplicate of [finding double in string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6734521/getting-a-double-out-of-a-string)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use scanner

```
String myString = "your string";
Scanner sc = new Scanner(myString);
double myDouble = sc.nextDouble();
```

Comment: when ı insert this code ı take Exception in thread "main" java.util.InputMismatchException
 at java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Unknown Source)
 at java.util.Scanner.next(Unknown Source)
 at java.util.Scanner.nextDouble(Unknown Source)

Comment: @ADKu That means you did it wrong: You are supposed to write a program that uses the ideas expressed in that code, not just plug those lines into your program in some arbitrary spot.

Comment: my text have lots of line but ı dont know how can scan lots of line. @Nimrod007 scaning only one line