# Get Double value from String

Tags: java, string, double

I Have got a String "To be above 10385.29 at 2:25pm".

I want get Double value from this String.

I try with Pattern and Matcher like:

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(\\w+?).(\\w+?)");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(instrumentName);

while (matcher.find()) {
    String key = matcher.group(1);
    String value = matcher.group(2);

    System.out.println("Key : " + key + " value : " + value);
}
```

But it works weird and do not find double value.

I want get as result `Double value = 10385.29`

This value can be like `xxx.xx` or `xxxxx.xx`. After dot always is two numbers but before can be two, five or more.

Comment: See [this demo](https://ideone.com/A4Uoay)

Comment: Make sure you understand exactly what the regular expression means. Currently it most likely does not mean what you think it means. Note that `.` is a special character in regular expressions. See the API docs of [`java.util.regex.Pattern`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/).

Comment: This has been answered already; see [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6734521/getting-a-double-out-of-a-string) for a few different solutions.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew That is it! Thanks! Post an answer and I will accepted it

Comment: Sorry, it turns out a dupe. No need answering.

Comment: There are three problems with the regex you are using.  1) you are matching "word" characters not "digits".  2) The dot between the groups needs to be escaped.  It currently matches any single character.  3) You actually need an greedy match to capture all of the digits after the decimal point.

Answer (score 2):

if the string value is stored like this "10385.29 2:25pm" then you can split it and use the parseDouble to get your double value like this:

```
    String ss = "10385.29 2:25pm";
    String vs[] = ss.split(" ");
    double val = Double.parseDouble(vs[0]);
    System.out.println(val);
```